# Achieving transparent column in two column slide in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, transition

I have a slide in latex beamer with two columns; each column containing a figure followed by text and an equation:

```
\frame{
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.4\textwidth]{ex1.pdf}
\vspace*{-0.45cm}
\caption{example 1}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-0.3cm}
ajeiwfif uoerifioerfeorf ioefepofieprf 
\end{column}

\begin{column}{6cm}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3.cm,width=0.4\textwidth]{ex2.pdf}
\vspace*{-0.45cm}
\caption{Example 2}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-0.3cm}
ajeiwfif uoerifioerfeorf ioefepofieprf 
\end{column}
\end{columns}
}
```

I want the first column to appear first and the second column to remain transparent. I have tried to achieve the same by using `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` and the commands related to it but after doing so the figure in the second column also appears along with the first column and only the text in the second column remains transparent. Does anyone have any idea on how to make both the figure and the text in the second column?I would highly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: For future questions, can you please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest would be to just draw a transparent rectangle above the second column.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}

    \begin{columns}

        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.4\textwidth]{pic}
                \vspace*{-0.45cm}
                \caption{example 1}
            \end{figure}
            \vspace*{-0.3cm}
            ajeiwfif uoerifioerfeorf ioefepofieprf 
        \end{column}

        \hfill

        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[height=3.cm,width=0.4\textwidth]{pic}
                \vspace*{-0.45cm}
                \caption{Example 2}
            \end{figure}
            \vspace*{-0.3cm}
            ajeiwfif uoerifioerfeorf ioefepofieprf 
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}

        \begin{onlyenv}<1>
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.80] 
            (current page.north) rectangle (current page.south east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{onlyenv} 

        \pause    

  \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! It worked but is there some way to reduce the height and increase the width of the transparent rectangle?(as the rectangle doesn't cover the the entire text in the second column)

Comment: Sure you can change them. The line `(current page.north) rectangle (current page.south east)` gives the coordinates of the rectangle with respect to the whole page. If you want to change them, just look up how coordinates work in tikz.